# In blender when an object is duplicate linked why are both meshes not showing up in the edit mode at the same time?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

When I create a duplicate linked object model in object mode most of its characteristics should be duplicated including the meshes of both. When I go into edit mode the two objects should show their meshes at the same time. When I try this, only the original mesh is highlighted. Why are not both meshes being shown in edit mode? This used to be the default behavior in Blender as shown at 3:02 in this video: https://youtu.be/ENdGhAM3NzA?t=182

Answer (score 3):

Two part answer:

1. When you duplicate an object, the data that is duplicated is configurable in Preferences, under the *Editing* tab.  Here are the defaults for 3.2:

[image: Preferences showing the default duplicates]

2. When you go into edit mode, the two object do not show their meshes at the same time as you have discovered.  This is a user interface design choice by the developers. While an edit updates both meshes in real time, only the active mesh is shown. This is to reduce confusion in the interface.

[image: Duplicate Suzanne being edited]

Comment: Thank you Marty for such a quick and clearly stated answer. I wish I could add to your badges but being a newbie to this site, don't know how.